# Changes in Apache SuperSet .less templates are not being applied to interface after build

Tags: apache-superset

I'm currently running Apache Superset which is working very well.

However, I've now received a requirement to make a few structural changes to the CSS layout and formatting of the Superset interface. Making changes to the dashboard CSS templates and config.py won't be sufficient. So what I would like to achieve is to make changes to the superset .less templates and have chose changes applied to the interface. However, so far I've not been able to successfully making any changes to the interface by changing the .less templates.

What I've tried to far is to:

1. Follow all the instructions to build my Apache Superset from source using the instructions here: https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#setup-local-environment-for-development
2. Make changes to the .less templates as described here: https://debaatobiee.wordpress.com/2019/08/04/customizing-apache-superset-ui-config-theme-changes/

However, after making changes to the .less templates, and rebuilding using "npm run build" and "npm run dev-server" in directory superset-frontend, it seems that those changes are not being applied.

Am I doing any steps incorrectly? I'm using a aws t3.large machine with Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS (HVM) x86 and I run the following commands from machine creation:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev python3-pip libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev libmysqlclient-dev python3.8-venv
git clone https://github.com/apache/superset.git
cd superset
python3 -m venv venv  
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements/development.txt
pip install pymssql
pip install -e .
superset db upgrade
superset fab create-admin
superset init
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.0/install.sh | bash
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
cd superset-frontend
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
npm ci
```

I edit the file ~/superset/superset-frontend/src/assets/stylesheets/less/variables.less as follows:

Replace **@primary-color: #20a7c9** with **@primary-color: #00ff00**

Now in one command prompt I run the following command:

```
FLASK_ENV=development superset run -p 8088 -h 0.0.0.0 --with-threads --reload --debugger
```

And in another command prompt I run the following:

```
npm run build
npm run dev-server
```

I can successfully connect to the page on port 9000. However, even after ctrl+f5 the css never seems to change according to the changes I made in the .less templates. In this example I would have expected the color to have changed (no more #20a7c9 in the css, but #00ff00 instead).

What am I doing incorrectly in my approach? Or is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to do (make site-wide LESS/CSS changes)? I've tried using Docker but I wasn't successful in making that work.

Answer (score 0):

After more testing I found that my changes from the .less templates were in fact being applied using the approach I mentioned. I had just not made enough changes in the .less templates to notice the difference. So by making more changes, and checking in the right places, I could change the Superset interface. Moving forward I've learned to make more rigorous changes and figure out how they influence the interface through trial and error. Still feels like an inefficient approach though - if there would be a quicker way to apply & test css / less changes instead of rebuilding that would be helpful.